# Get Row Number (int) from mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli

For example i have 3 rows in my query. And i was execute it with while mysql_fetch_array.

So the code become like this

```
$query = "select * from schedule where kode_schedule = '".$q."'";
$query_exec = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_exec))
{
   // i want to echo row number //
   echo $data['kode_schedule'];
   echo $data['nim'];
}
```

So the result become like this :

```
1 | KD_0001  | 32110024

2 | KD_0002 | 32110023

3 | KD_0003 | 32110022
```

The main question is how to get the row number? `{1 , 2 , 3}`

Comment: I think you were getting as shown within your posts result

Comment: There is no such thing as a row number, you can either use an auto increment or a php counter for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a counter and increment it in every iteration -

```
$i = 1;
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_exec))
{
   echo $i . '|' . $data['kode_schedule'] . '|' . $data['nim'];
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the row number in the query itself:

```
select @rn := @rn+1 AS RowNumber,t1.* from (

     select * from schedule where kode_schedule = XXXXX

) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2 ;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your data table has **Unique ID (Primary Key)** in serial then don't you think it's **row number** ?

or you can do this:

```
 <?php

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   echo '
    <tr>
        <td>No '.($i + $offset).'</td>
        <td>'.$row[username].'</td>
        <td>'.$row[value].'</td>
    </tr>';
    $i++;

 }

?>
```

Comment: [Reference](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/php-mysql-display-record-643567.html)